# OS X用プログラムでファイルとフォルダを圧縮したい

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

Xcode7.0+Swift2でファイル圧縮用のOS X(Cocoa)アプリケーションをつくろうとしています。
圧縮に用いているライブラリは[ZipArchive](https://github.com/ZipArchive/ZipArchive)(旧SSZipArchive)というもので、次の2つの関数を備えています。

・複数のファイルから圧縮ファイルを作る
createZipFileAtPath(保存先, withFilesAtPaths: ファイルパスの配列)

・単一のフォルダとその内容から圧縮ファイルを作る
createZipFileAtPath(保存先, withContentsOfDirectory: フォルダパス)

ファイルのみ、フォルダ一つならこれらの関数で圧縮ファイルを作ることができますが、複数のファイルと複数のフォルダを元に圧縮ファイルを作りたい場合、withFilesAtPathsにフォルダパスを混ぜることはできないようです。

その場合一時的にフォルダを１つ作り、その中に圧縮する内容をすべてコピーしておき、withContentsOfDirectoryのほうで圧縮すれば良さそうなのですが、小さなファイルなら一瞬でも、大きなファイルを圧縮する際は一時フォルダへのコピーに時間がかかります。

可能なら直接的にフォルダ、ファイルの混在する圧縮ファイルを作りたいのですがそういう方法はあるのでしょうか？
別のライブラリでも構いません。

---

【追記】
質問から日にちが経ったため開発環境が Swift 1.x→2.xに変わりました。

Answer (score 1):

こんにちは。そのライブラリは使ったことはないので良い回答はできないのですが。

そういう目的であれば、そのライブラリを使わずに標準の libz.dylib ライブラリを使ってご自身のプログラム中で目的の複数ファイルと複数フォルダを回してひとつづつ ZIP していけばいいのではないでしょうか。

一部だけですが

```
- (NSData *)zlibInflate
{
    if ( [self length] == 0 )
    {
        return self;
    }

    NSUInteger full_length = [self length];
    NSUInteger half_length = full_length / 2;
    NSMutableData *decompressed = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:(full_length + half_length)];
    int status;
    z_stream strm;

    strm.next_in = (Bytef *)[self bytes];
    strm.avail_in = (NMUInt)full_length;
    strm.total_out = 0;
    strm.zalloc = Z_NULL;
    strm.zfree = Z_NULL;

    if ( inflateInit (&strm) == Z_OK )
    {
        BOOL done = FALSE;

        while ( ! done )
        {
            if ( strm.total_out >= [decompressed length] )
            {
                [decompressed increaseLengthBy:half_length];
            }

            strm.next_out = [decompressed mutableBytes] + strm.total_out;
            strm.avail_out = ( [decompressed length] - strm.total_out );

            status = inflate (&strm, Z_SYNC_FLUSH);

            if ( status == Z_STREAM_END )
            {
                done = TRUE;
            }
            else if ( status != Z_OK )
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        if ( inflateEnd (&strm) == Z_OK )
        {
            if ( done )
            {
                [decompressed setLength:strm.total_out];

                return [NSData dataWithData:decompressed];
            }
        }
    }

    return self;
}
```

ご参考になれば。

Comment: Xcodeのバージョンが7.0に上がった関係でもともとあった「libz.dylib」がなくなり、似た名前で「libz.tbd」や「libz.1.2.5.tbd」などが追加されたようですがどれを使えば良いのでしょうか。

Answer (score -1):

コピーが時間かかるなら、代わりに symbolic link でいかがでしょうか。

Comment: シンボリックリンクを試してみましたがリンクを辿ってくれずに実体のないデータになってしまうようです。